# Change the value of ref inside a child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to change the value of the ref, which is in the parent component, from the child component. I tried using emits or passing the ref to the child component and change it there, but no success since when I'm trying to access the ref in the child component, I get the value of it, but not the actual wrapper of the ref.

Main component (simplified):

```
<template>
  <FormFields
  :username="username"
  :password="password"
  :usernameRef="usernameRef"
  :passwordRef="passwordRef"
  :usernameErrorRef="usernameErrorRef"
  :passwordErrorRef="passwordErrorRef"
  @clearError="clearError"
/>
</template>


setup() {
  ...

  const usernameRef = ref('')
  const passwordRef = ref('')

  const usernameErrorRef = ref('');
  const passwordErrorRef = ref('');

  // This is sent as a emit function to child component which will clear the error refs when user focuses on the input which is inside the child component
  const clearError = (ref) => {
    ref.value = '';
  };

  return {
    ...
  }
```

FormFields component (simplified):

```
<template>
  <FormFieldWrapper :errorRef="usernameErrorRef">
    <input v-model="usernameRef" @focus="$emit('clearError', usernameErrorRef)" />
  </FormFieldWrapper>
  <FormFieldWrapper :errorRef="passwordErrorRef">
    <input v-model="passwordRef" @focus="$emit('clearError', passwordErrorRef)" />
  </FormFieldWrapper>
</template>
```

FormFieldWrapper (simplified):

```
<template>
  <p>
    <label>
      <slot></slot>
    </label>
    <span class="error">{{errorRef}}</span>
  </p>
</template>
```

With this approach, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'value' on string ''
```

I tried even changing the ref without emitting, directly changing it:

```
<input
  @focus="usernameErrorRef.value = ''"
/>
```

But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to change the value of the ref, which is in the parent component, from the child component.

Props should not be mutated, as documented [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#one-way-data-flow)

The correct way to establish two-way data flow in components is by combining a prop and a custom event. The `v-model` directive is syntax sugar for this pattern, as documented [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#using-v-model-on-components)

[Here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8aDE+e3sgbWVzc2FnZSB9fTwvaDE+XG4gIDxjaGlsZC1jb21wb25lbnQgdi1tb2RlbDptZXNzYWdlPVwibWVzc2FnZVwiPjwvY2hpbGQtY29tcG9uZW50PlxuPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT5cblxuPHNjcmlwdD5cbiAgaW1wb3J0IHsgcmVmIH0gZnJvbSAndnVlJ1xuICBpbXBvcnQgQ2hpbGRDb21wb25lbnQgZnJvbSAnLi9DaGlsZENvbXBvbmVudC52dWUnXG4gIGV4cG9ydCBkZWZhdWx0IHtcbiAgICBjb21wb25lbnRzOiB7XG4gICAgICBDaGlsZENvbXBvbmVudFxuICAgIH0sXG4gICAgc2V0dXAoKSB7XG4gICAgICBjb25zdCBtZXNzYWdlID0gcmVmKCdoZWxsbyB3b3JsZCEnKVxuICAgICAgXG4gICAgICByZXR1cm4geyBtZXNzYWdlIH1cbiAgICB9XG4gIH1cbjwvc2NyaXB0PiIsIkNoaWxkQ29tcG9uZW50LnZ1ZSI6Ijx0ZW1wbGF0ZT5cblx0PGlucHV0IEBmb2N1cz1cIm1vZGVsID0gJydcIiB2LW1vZGVsPVwibW9kZWxcIj5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+XG5cbjxzY3JpcHQ+XG5pbXBvcnQgeyBjb21wdXRlZCB9IGZyb20gJ3Z1ZSdcbmV4cG9ydCBkZWZhdWx0IHtcbiAgcHJvcHM6IHtcbiAgICBtZXNzYWdlOiBTdHJpbmdcbiAgfSxcbiAgc2V0dXAocHJvcHMsIHsgZW1pdCB9KSB7XG4gICAgLy8gd2UgdXNlIGEgY29tcHV0ZWQgd2l0aCBhIHNldHRlciB0byBwcm94eSBvdXIgcHJvcFxuXHRcdC8vIHdoZW5ldmVyIHdlIGF0ZW1wdCB0byB1cGRhdGUgdGhpcywgZW1pdCBhbiBldmVudCB3aXRoIHRoZSBuZXcgdmFsdWUuXG4gICAgLy8gdGhlIHBhcmVudCBjb21wb25lbnQgd2lsbCByZWNlaXZlIHRoZSBldmVudCBhbmQgdXBkYXRlIHRoZSBwcm9wXG4gICAgY29uc3QgbW9kZWwgPSBjb21wdXRlZCh7XG4gICAgICBnZXQ6ICgpID0+IHByb3BzLm1lc3NhZ2UsXG4gICAgICBzZXQ6IHZhbHVlID0+IGVtaXQoJ3VwZGF0ZTptZXNzYWdlJywgdmFsdWUpXG4gICAgfSlcbiAgICBcbiAgICByZXR1cm4geyBtb2RlbCB9XG4gIH1cbn1cbjwvc2NyaXB0PiJ9) is a link to a working example on the Vue SFC Playground

I also want to address this:

> I tried even changing the ref without emitting, directly changing it:
>
> ```
> <input
>  @focus="usernameErrorRef.value = ''"
> />
> ```

This will not work. References are unwrapped in the template so you do not access their value through the `value` property, you can mutate them directly instead (which does not work in your case for other reasons)
This is documented [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#usage-with-templates)